# Reducing bandwidth of op amp to eliminate op amp parasitic oscillation

Tags: operational-amplifier, bandwidth

I am using few op amps to amplify a signal coming from a FGEN. My signal from FGEN is around 500Khz-7.5Mhz. Now regardless of the supply, even when the FGEN is disconnected and power the op amp using DC supply the op amp starts oscillating.

I read here in StackExchange that by increasing the feedback resistor value or in other words increasing the op amp gain will reduce the bandwidth of the op amp and thus remove those unwanted oscillation. So today I changed the feedback resistors from 1k to 20K and then the oscillations were gone and when i turned on the FGEN it worked nicely.

Now since its a huge gain that i am getting right now my supervisor asked me to use a capacitor in parallel to the feedback resistor without increasing the resistor value itself. He said by that we can reduce the op amp bandwidth and solve the problem without having such high gain. Can anybody suggest me how to do it. I am sharing [the op-amp datasheet](https://www.ti.com/product/THS6012?keyMatch=THS6012DWP&tisearch=Search-EN-everything&usecase=GPN) and the screenshot of the circuit for your kind considerations.

The power supply decoupling capacitors are there.. Sorry they are not being shown in the diagram. the 68 mohm resistors are there to decouple them from the load. Like i said when i increased the feedback resistors to 20K the parasitic oscillation was gone. Any suggestion how to select the capacitor value that i will connect parallel to the feedback resistance (keeping its value to 1k) to get the similar behaviour. I used the equation fc= 1/(2*pi*C*R) to determine the cutoff frequency and select the capaciotrs based on that. but it didnt work the oscilations were still there. It only goes away when I put feedback resistor value to more than 15k.

Regards,
Zakaria
[image]

Comment: You have to be kidding about the two 68 milli ohm resistors? Minimum load resistance is about 10 ohms. Also where are your power supply decoupling capacitors?

Comment: @Andyaka I think those are supposed to be current balancing resistors, which makes their magnitudes a lot more reasonable, but still seems pretty low, but maybe the two circuits are well matched.

Comment: @DKNguyen why would the input be shown like it is in the circuit if what you say is true?

Comment: @Andyaka Oh, I guess that's true. The two amps aren't just in parallel.